# No free option suggested when creating an RDS database with an SQL Server engine on AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and I've been stuck on trying to create a free RDS database with SQL Server engine. In all tutorials, it says that I can choose the free option template. But, when I select SQL Server as engine, I don't get any suggestions for templates below the choice of the engine (see first screenshot) as shown in the tutorials and there's no free option to select anywhere and it shows monthly costs below (see second screenshot) . I am really confused on why I don't have the free option!

I hope someone has any idea [image]
[image]

Comment: As I know it is applicable for combination of DB instance size=db.t2.micro, Storage=20 GB of type GP-SSD. Furthermore, in AWS web console you need turn on Include previous generation classes during selection of DB instance size as well as SQL Server version must be SQL Server 2017 or previous.

Comment: You could also use LocalDB for free on your PC

Comment: @amitd actually changing the version to 2017 solved the problem ! I do now have a Templates section including Free tier option! you can post this as a solution. But I didn't understand why u think that I need to turn on Include previous generation classes ?

Comment: @adarch-darchif - I mentioned to turn on Include previous generation classes to allow choosing "db.t2.micro", as [this](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23databases) aws documentation says 12 MONTHS FREE is applicable for 750 Hours per month of "db.t2.micro" database usage. Posted same as a solution.

Comment: In my case the issue was with the region I selected. I had selected Stockholm. Apparently some regions do not support free tier. I changed to US-East-1 and the free tier option appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know it is applicable for combination of DB instance size=db.t2.micro, Storage=20 GB of type GP-SSD. Furthermore, in AWS web console you need turn on Include previous generation classes during selection of DB instance size as well as SQL Server version must be SQL Server 2017 or previous.

Comment: I was trying to setup a postgres instance and the solution for me was simply switching to an earlier version. Once I switched the option appeared.

Comment: Currently Postgres version 12 has free tier. Selecting any version of 13 makes free tier option gets disabled.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Free Tier page here:

https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%2312monthsfree&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=categories%23databases

SQL Server is listed as part of Free Tier for 750 hours.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. I am aware that is eligible to the free tier, but the problem is I can't find a way to choose the free tier. I have an estimated monthly cost of 37.7 dollars !

Comment: If you look at this calculator here https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html. It states inbound is free and you can use up to 1 GB for outbound free as well.